# Android Studio--- Android resource linking failed problem

Tags: kotlin, android-studio

Hello i am trying to learn android studio with their developer education.
So for short i did everything they said but i have this problem when i run the app i tried everyting in the internet still couldnt find a solution

exact problem lane

Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\bahri\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:17: error: resource style/Theme.MyApplication (aka com.example.myapplication:style/Theme.MyApplication) not found.
error: failed processing manifest.

this is activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/primary_color"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/button" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/secondary_color"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:contentDescription="@string/email_icon"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</LinearLayout>
```

this is build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.myapplication"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk = 19
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}
```

I tried to rename the style name , change the sdk version , adding additional implementation on the build gradle